# dplyr filter incorrectly on variable condition

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm having a strange behavior when using dplyr's `filter`. I have the following data structures:

```
ALPHA <- 28
DELTA <- 7 

df: 

    age        v     n
   <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1    28 6.09e-10     1
 2    29 1.93e- 9     1
 3    30 5.94e- 9     1
 4    31 1.78e- 8     1
 5    32 5.19e- 8     1
 6    33 1.47e- 7     1
 7    34 4.05e- 7     1
 8    35 1.09e- 6     1
 9    36 2.83e- 6     1
10    37 7.18e- 6     1
```

If I run:

```
df %>% filter(age == (ALPHA + DELTA))
```

I get a null return. Letting `x <- ALPHA + DELTA` and then `df %>% filter(age == x)` returns null.  However, `df %>% filter(age == 35)` gives the desired return.

Is there a way of filtering on variable conditions in dplyr?  Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of your data? Try `dput(head(df))`. If I try it with `mtcars`, it works for me: `t1 <- 3; t2 <- 1; dplyr::filter(mtcars, gear == (t1 + t2))`. Are you sure you're using `dplyr::filter` and not `stats::filter`?

Comment: What happens if you convert age to an integer column?

Comment: can you do dput(df), or dput(head(df,20)) if it is too long? I cannot reproduce your error

Comment: df = structure(list(age = c(28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37
), v = c(6.09e-10, 1.93e-09, 5.94e-09, 1.78e-08, 5.19e-08, 1.47e-07, 
4.05e-07, 1.09e-06, 2.83e-06, 7.18e-06), n = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame")) ; df %>% filter(age == (ALPHA + DELTA)) ; it works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be an issue of floating point.  One option is to convert the 'age' to `integer` and do the `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(as.integer(age) == (ALPHA + DELTA))
```

Comment: This turned out to be the issue.  Thank you!